# Rundeck get verbose output of command executing on node

Tags: bash, python, automation

I have [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org) executing a remote script, which is in python is using print statements to return output normally such as:

```
$ python mytest.py 
PASS: Condition 1 passed
PASS: Condition 2 passed
PASS: and so on...
```

When I run this via Rundeck, however, it doesn't show me the same `print` generated outputs as above. In Rundeck's most detailed Debug output mode, I only receive the following:

```
06:31:12    Permanently added 'myremotenode.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
06:31:12    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
06:31:12    SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
06:31:12    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
06:31:13    SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
06:31:13    Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
06:31:13    Next authentication method: publickey
06:31:13    Authentication succeeded (publickey).
06:31:13    /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Mozil...
06:32:06    Adding reference: ant.PropertyHelper
06:32:06    Setting project property: sshexec.output -> /cygdrive/c/Prog...
```

I know that the remote script is actually executing just as usual, as I'm receiving other emails generated by the ~30min long script.

Obviously, I don't want to have to wait 30mins to see the result of each print statement within the python script.

How can I get the same level of output in Rundeck as I do in the bash shell directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO question on [python output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering) solved it for me.

Adding the `-u` flag to the python execution line remedied whatever was redirecting the output for Rundeck.